# carro compras con symfony3 y jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony3

Necesito mantener actualizado el carrito de compras con los productos que se agregan. Con jQuery pude encontrar la forma para agregarlos localmente pero no puedo persistirlos y/o mantenerlos en una session. Lo que necesito es q al navegar mantenga esos productos y sòlo me solicite el login al querer hacer "checkout" de los productos agregados.

Les dejo el còdigo comunidad, gracias.

controller.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajax", name="ajax")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $items =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cart')->findOneBy(array('id'=> $this->getUser()->getId()));
        if ($items){
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(200);
            $response->setData(array(
                'response' => 'success',
                'items' => $serializer->serialize($items, 'json')
            ));

            return $response;
        }
    }
    return new Response('No ajax', 400);
}

/**
 * @Route("/ajax_save", name="ajax_save")
 * @Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function ajaxsaveAction(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if ($user){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $content = $request->getContent();
            $params = json_decode($content, true);
            $cart = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cart')->findOneBy(array('user'=> $user, 'product'=> $params['id']));

            if ($cart){
                $cart->setQuantity($cart->getQuantity() + $params['quantity']);
                $em->persist($cart);
                $em->flush();

            } else {
                $cart_new = new Cart();
                $cart_new->setUser($user);
                $cart_new->setQuantity($params['quantity']);
                $cart_new->setProduct($em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($params['id']));
                $em->persist($cart_new);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => 'OK'));
    }

    return new Response('No es ajax!', 400);

}
```

base.html.twig

```
$(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "{{ path('ajax') }}",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });

                    var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
                        var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
                        var $image = $('<img width="40px" height="40px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
                        $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
                        var position = $cartIcon.position();
                        $image.animate({
                            top: position.top,
                            left: position.left
                        }, 800 , "linear", function() {
                            $image.remove();
                        });
                    };

                    window.prod = [];

                    $('.my-cart-btn').myCart({
                        currencySymbol: '$',
                        classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
                        classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
                        classProductQuantity: 'my-product-quantity',
                        classProductRemove: 'my-product-remove',
                        classCheckoutCart: 'my-cart-checkout',
                        affixCartIcon: true,
                        showCheckoutModal: true,
                        numberOfDecimals: 2,
                        cartItems: [

                        ],

                        clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
                            goToCartIcon($addTocart);

                        },
                        afterAddOnCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
                            console.log("despues de adherir", products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "{{ path('ajax_save') }}",
                                data: {
                                    id: this.id, name: this.name, summary: this.summary, price: this.price, quantity: this.quantity, image: this.image
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);

                                }
                            });
                        },
                        clickOnCartIcon: function($cartIcon, products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
                            console.log("cart icon clicked", $cartIcon, products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
                        },
                        checkoutCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
                            var checkoutString = "Total Price: " + totalPrice + "\nTotal Quantity: " + totalQuantity;
                            checkoutString += "\n\n id \t name \t summary \t price \t quantity \t image path";
                            $.each(products, function(){
                                checkoutString += ("\n " + this.id + " \t " + this.name + " \t " + this.summary + " \t " + this.price + " \t " + this.quantity + " \t " + this.image);
                            });
                            alert(checkoutString);
                            console.log("checking out", products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);

                        },
                        getDiscountPrice: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
                            console.log("calculando descuento", products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
                            return totalPrice;
                        }
                    });

                });
```

jqueryMyCart.js

```
(function ($) {
```

"use strict";

var OptionManager = (function () {
    var objToReturn = {};

```
var _options = null;
var DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  currencySymbol: '$',
  classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
  classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
  classProductQuantity: 'my-product-quantity',
  classProductRemove: 'my-product-remove',
  classCheckoutCart: 'my-cart-checkout',
  affixCartIcon: true,
  showCheckoutModal: true,
  numberOfDecimals: 2,
  cartItems: [],
  clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart) { },
  afterAddOnCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) { },
  clickOnCartIcon: function($cartIcon, products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) { },
  checkoutCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) { },
  getDiscountPrice: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) { return null; }
};


var loadOptions = function (customOptions) {
  _options = $.extend({}, DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
  if (typeof customOptions === 'object') {
    $.extend(_options, customOptions);
  }
}
var getOptions = function () {
  return _options;
}

objToReturn.loadOptions = loadOptions;
objToReturn.getOptions = getOptions;
return objToReturn;
```

}());

var MathHelper = (function() {
    var objToReturn = {};
    var getRoundedNumber = function(number){
      var options = OptionManager.getOptions();
      return number.toFixed(options.numberOfDecimals);
    }
    objToReturn.getRoundedNumber = getRoundedNumber;
    return objToReturn;
  }());

var ProductManager = (function(){
    var objToReturn = {};

```
/*
PRIVATE
*/
localStorage.products = localStorage.products ? localStorage.products : "";
var getIndexOfProduct = function(id){
  var productIndex = -1;
  var products = getAllProducts();
  $.each(products, function(index, value){
    if(value.id == id){
      productIndex = index;
      return;
    }
  });
  return productIndex;
}
var setAllProducts = function(products){
  localStorage.products = JSON.stringify(products);
}
var addProduct = function(id, name, summary, price, quantity, image) {
  var products = getAllProducts();
  products.push({
    id: id,
    name: name,
    summary: summary,
    price: price,
    quantity: quantity,
    image: image
  });
  setAllProducts(products);
}

/*
PUBLIC
*/
var getAllProducts = function(){
  try {
    var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.products);
    return products;
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
}
var updatePoduct = function(id, quantity) {
  var productIndex = getIndexOfProduct(id);
  if(productIndex < 0){
    return false;
  }
  var products = getAllProducts();
  products[productIndex].quantity = typeof quantity === "undefined" ? products[productIndex].quantity * 1 + 1 : quantity;
  setAllProducts(products);
  return true;
}
var setProduct = function(id, name, summary, price, quantity, image) {
  if(typeof id === "undefined"){
    console.error("id requerido")
    return false;
  }
  if(typeof name === "undefined"){
    console.error("nombre requerido")
    return false;
  }
  if(typeof image === "undefined"){
    console.error("imagen requerida")
    return false;
  }
  if(!$.isNumeric(price)){
    console.error("el precio no es un número")
    return false;
  }
  if(!$.isNumeric(quantity)) {
    console.error("cantidad no es un número");
    return false;
  }
  summary = typeof summary === "undefined" ? "" : summary;

  if(!updatePoduct(id)){
    addProduct(id, name, summary, price, quantity, image);
  }
}
var clearProduct = function(){
  setAllProducts([]);
}
var removeProduct = function(id){
  var products = getAllProducts();
  products = $.grep(products, function(value, index) {
    return value.id != id;
  });
  setAllProducts(products);
}
var getTotalQuantity = function(){
  var total = 0;
  var products = getAllProducts();
  $.each(products, function(index, value){
    total += value.quantity * 1;
  });
  return total;
}
var getTotalPrice = function(){
  var products = getAllProducts();
  var total = 0;
  $.each(products, function(index, value){
    total += value.quantity * value.price;
    total = MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(total) * 1;
  });
  return total;
}

objToReturn.getAllProducts = getAllProducts;
objToReturn.updatePoduct = updatePoduct;
objToReturn.setProduct = setProduct;
objToReturn.clearProduct = clearProduct;
objToReturn.removeProduct = removeProduct;
objToReturn.getTotalQuantity = getTotalQuantity;
objToReturn.getTotalPrice = getTotalPrice;
return objToReturn;
```

}());

var loadMyCartEvent = function(){

```
var options = OptionManager.getOptions();
var $cartIcon = $("." + options.classCartIcon);
var $cartBadge = $("." + options.classCartBadge);
var classProductQuantity = options.classProductQuantity;
var classProductRemove = options.classProductRemove;
var classCheckoutCart = options.classCheckoutCart;

var idCartModal = 'my-cart-modal';
var idCartTable = 'my-cart-table';
var idGrandTotal = 'my-cart-grand-total';
var idEmptyCartMessage = 'my-cart-empty-message';
var idDiscountPrice = 'my-cart-discount-price';
var classProductTotal = 'my-product-total';
var classAffixMyCartIcon = 'my-cart-icon-affix';


if(options.cartItems && options.cartItems.constructor === Array) {
  ProductManager.clearProduct();
  $.each(options.cartItems, function() {
    ProductManager.setProduct(this.id, this.name, this.summary, this.price, this.quantity, this.image);
  });
}

$cartBadge.text(ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());

if(!$("#" + idCartModal).length) {
  $('body').append(
    '<div class="modal fade" id="' + idCartModal + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">' +
    '<div class="modal-content">' +
    '<div class="modal-header">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
    '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Mi Carrito</h4>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-body">' +
    '<table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="' + idCartTable + '"></table>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="modal-footer">' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ' + classCheckoutCart + '">Comprar</button>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
  );
}

var drawTable = function(){
  var $cartTable = $("#" + idCartTable);
  $cartTable.empty();

  var products = ProductManager.getAllProducts();
  $.each(products, function(){
    var total = this.quantity * this.price;
    $cartTable.append(
      '<tr title="' + this.summary + '" data-id="' + this.id + '" data-price="' + this.price + '">' +
      '<td class="text-center" style="width: 40px;"><img width="40px" height="40px" src="' + this.image + '"/></td>' +
      '<td>' + this.name + '</td>' +
      '<td title="PrecioUnitario">' + options.currencySymbol + MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(this.price) + '</td>' +
      '<td title="Cantidad"><input type="number" min="1" style="width: 70px;" class="' + classProductQuantity + '" value="' + this.quantity + '"/></td>' +
      '<td title="Total" class="' + classProductTotal + '">' + options.currencySymbol  + MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(total) + '</td>' +
      '<td title="Eliminar del Carrito" class="text-center" style="width: 30px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger ' + classProductRemove + '">X</a></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });

  $cartTable.append(products.length ?
    '<tr>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td><strong>Total</strong></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td><strong id="' + idGrandTotal + '"></strong></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '</tr>'
    : '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="' + idEmptyCartMessage + '">Tu Carro está Vacío</div>'
  );

  var discountPrice = options.getDiscountPrice(products, ProductManager.getTotalPrice(), ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
  if(products.length && discountPrice !== null) {
    $cartTable.append(
      '<tr style="color: red">' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '<td><strong>Total (Incluyendo Descuentos)</strong></td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '<td><strong id="' + idDiscountPrice + '"></strong></td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  }

  showGrandTotal();
  showDiscountPrice();
}
var showModal = function(){
  drawTable();
  $("#" + idCartModal).modal('show');
}
var updateCart = function(){
  $.each($("." + classProductQuantity), function(){
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
    ProductManager.updatePoduct(id, $(this).val());
  });
}
var showGrandTotal = function(){
  $("#" + idGrandTotal).text(options.currencySymbol + MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(ProductManager.getTotalPrice()));
}
var showDiscountPrice = function(){
  $("#" + idDiscountPrice).text(options.currencySymbol + MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(options.getDiscountPrice(ProductManager.getAllProducts(), ProductManager.getTotalPrice(), ProductManager.getTotalQuantity())));
}

/*
EVENT
*/
if(options.affixCartIcon) {
  var cartIconBottom = $cartIcon.offset().top * 1 + $cartIcon.css("height").match(/\d+/) * 1;
  var cartIconPosition = $cartIcon.css('position');
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    $(window).scrollTop() >= cartIconBottom ? $cartIcon.addClass(classAffixMyCartIcon) : $cartIcon.removeClass(classAffixMyCartIcon);
  });
}

$cartIcon.click(function(){
  options.showCheckoutModal ? showModal() : options.clickOnCartIcon($cartIcon, ProductManager.getAllProducts(), ProductManager.getTotalPrice(), ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
});

$(document).on("input", "." + classProductQuantity, function () {
  var price = $(this).closest("tr").data("price");
  var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
  var quantity = $(this).val();

  $(this).parent("td").next("." + classProductTotal).text(options.currencySymbol + MathHelper.getRoundedNumber(price * quantity));
  ProductManager.updatePoduct(id, quantity);

  $cartBadge.text(ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
  showGrandTotal();
  showDiscountPrice();
});

$(document).on('keypress', "." + classProductQuantity, function(evt){
  if(evt.keyCode == 38 || evt.keyCode == 40){
    return ;
  }
  evt.preventDefault();
});

$(document).on('click', "." + classProductRemove, function(){
  var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var id = $tr.data("id");
  $tr.hide(500, function(){
    ProductManager.removeProduct(id);
    drawTable();
    $cartBadge.text(ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
  });
});

$("." + classCheckoutCart).click(function(){
  var products = ProductManager.getAllProducts();
  if(!products.length) {
    $("#" + idEmptyCartMessage).fadeTo('fast', 0.5).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    return ;
  }
  updateCart();
  options.checkoutCart(ProductManager.getAllProducts(), ProductManager.getTotalPrice(), ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
  ProductManager.clearProduct();
  $cartBadge.text(ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
  $("#" + idCartModal).modal("hide");
});
```

}

var MyCart = function (target) {
    /*
    PRIVATE
    */
    var $target = $(target);
    var options = OptionManager.getOptions();
    var $cartIcon = $("." + options.classCartIcon);
    var $cartBadge = $("." + options.classCartBadge);

```
/*
EVENT
*/
$target.click(function(){
  options.clickOnAddToCart($target);

  var id = $target.data('id');
  var name = $target.data('name');
  var summary = $target.data('summary');
  var price = $target.data('price');
  var quantity = $target.data('quantity');
  var image = $target.data('image');

  ProductManager.setProduct(id, name, summary, price, quantity, image);
  $cartBadge.text(ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());

  options.afterAddOnCart(ProductManager.getAllProducts(), ProductManager.getTotalPrice(), ProductManager.getTotalQuantity());
});
```

}

$.fn.myCart = function (userOptions) {
    OptionManager.loadOptions(userOptions);
    loadMyCartEvent();
    return $.each(this, function () {
      new MyCart(this);
    });
  }

})(jQuery);

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de problema te dio cuando lo intentaste con las sesiones? En mi opinión son la manera más cómoda de "mantener" los elementos de un carrito hasta que se haga el checkout.

Comment: Ahora opte por eso. Estoy usando sesiones pero sin jquery para mantener los productos agregados en el carrito. Soy bastante nuevo en symfony y no sabía cual era la mejor manera.

Comment: La mejor manera suele ser la que funciona. Y siempre suele haber varias. Pero aun no me queda claro dónde está tu problema. Podrías volver a especificarlo?

Answer (score 0):

En el ajaxsaveAction tienes `$user = $this->getUser(); if($user)` es decir que si anonymous no va a entrar a ejecutar la función